# 3D S Payment callback issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, 3d-secure

I'm working on a payment system with React-Native. I want to do research on how to apply 3D payment methods. I want to listen to an event happening on my server on the client side. actually i only need this for the following reason. I feel there is something I got wrong here.

**3D Secure Steps**

- I send the product to be purchased to a service named iyzico with
  credit card information.
- If the information entered is correct, it gives me an answer as below.
- There is a special field here and I need to decrypto it and show it to the user.
- In fact, this crypoto information contains an html page.
- By decoding this code, I show the user an html page.
- The password sent to the user's phone via SMS is entered on that
  screen and presses the confirmation button.

The part I don't understand starts here. The person is in a true asynchronous. I want to callback. Because he can enter or cancel the password sent by SMS whenever he wants.

I'm not wondering how the process turned out. How will we inform the client application only in this case?

Should we use push notifications or other push services for this?

The client has to get information about this process. According to the information he receives, I would like to suggest that your payment is successful or your balance is insufficient.

I know that I should avoid making circular calls.

In short, how should I listen to the client for an event that will take place on my server? Which would be the best method?

I am working on React-native and I do not want to include push services in the application just for this. It is costly for me to this. I believe it is a more beautiful solution.

What do you think about this subject?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You either need push notifications or long polling.  https://ably.com/blog/websockets-vs-long-polling